# Issue sending json request in django

Tags: python, json, django, django-views

i am working on a project and i want to encorporate SynapseFi api call into my django project. Looking at their documentation, they ask for a few parameters which I have add into a django function/method that is called to send a request to eh api and receive a response. I am not sure where, but i can not get it to work and i have been working on figuring this out for a few days. Maybe someone here can help.. I will add the documentation portion and what i have so far...

***Documentation***
The following is going to be added to the header of the request...

```
POST /v3.1/users HTTP/1.1
Host: uat-api.synapsefi.com
X-SP-GATEWAY: client_id_2bb1e412edd311e6bd04e285d6015267|client_secret_2bb1e714edd311e6bd04e285d6015267
X-SP-USER-IP: 127.0.0.1
X-SP-USER: |e83cf6ddcf778e37bfe3d48fc78a6502062fc
Content-Type: application/json
```

And this is a sample object that is going to be passed with the response...

```
{
  "logins": [
    {
      "email": "test@synapsepay.com"
    }
  ],
  "phone_numbers": [
    "901.111.1111",
    "test@synapsepay.com"
  ],
  "legal_names": [
    "Test User"
  ],
  "extra": {
    "supp_id": "122eddfgbeafrfvbbb",
    "cip_tag":1,
    "is_business": false
  }
}
```

*** My Code ***

this is what I have in a function that will be called from a method....

the headers goes into the request headers with the main url and the payload.

Is there a way to permanently set the key-value pairs in the headers once permanently and leave them there instead of having to add them with each request header....

```
url = 'uat-api.synapsefi.com'
headers = {
    'X-SP-GATEWAY' : client_id_asdfeavea561va9685e1gre5ara|client_secret_4651av5sa1edgvawegv1a6we1v5a6s51gv,
    'X-SP-USER-IP' : 127.0.0.1,
    'X-SP-USER' : | 'ge85a41v8e16v1a618gea164g65',
    'Contant-Type' : application/json,
}
payload = {
    "logins":[
        {
            "email":"test@test.com
        }
    ],
    "phone_numbers":[
        "123.456.7890",
        "test@test.com",
    ],
    "legal_names":[
        "Test name",
    ],
    "extras":{
        "supp_id":"asdfe515641e56wg",
        "cip_tag":12,
        "is_business":false,
    }
}

call = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(call)
return call
```

I am getting a syntax error on line:

```
'X-SP-GATEWAY' : client_id_asdfeavea561va9685e1gre5ara|client_secret_4651av5sa1edgvawegv1a6we1v5a6s51gv,
```

I just want to send a test request that works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String values need to be in quotes:

```
headers = {
    'X-SP-GATEWAY' : 'client_id_asdfeavea561va9685e1gre5ara|client_secret_4651av5sa1edgvawegv1a6we1v5a6s51gv'
    'X-SP-USER-IP' : '127.0.0.1',
    'X-SP-USER' : 'ge85a41v8e16v1a618gea164g65',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
```

}

Comment: i fixed that issue but now i am getting an error that says json is not defined in the request...have to import json right...